Configurator based on Inventor Model States
We have set of Inventor model that has multiple 'model states'. Now in web viewer, we need to switch model based on model states i.e. configurator based on model states.
I would like to know if, while converting an Inventor assembly to SVF using the Model Derivative APIs, the model states are preserved or discarded. Do you have any suggestions for achieving this in the APS viewer?
Thank you.

The Model Derivative API will always translate the active Model State and active Design View. Unfortunately, it does not provide settings to control that.
If you need to generate SVF for a different Model State then you could e.g. use the Design Automation API to change the Model State and either also generate the SVF directly there or generate it then using the Model Derivative API
Once you have multiple model states translated to SVF then of course you could load whichever you need.

Thank you Adam. Your explanation answers my question.
